# How to work with the paging option of an API service in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a movie app with MVVM architecture, the API has a paging option and in the call, I have to pass the page number to the API. how should I implement paging in my app? i should mention that the Api gives good data about the page numbers and current page.

data class:

```
data class Metadata(
val current_page: String,
val page_count: Int,
val per_page: Int,
val total_count: Int
)
```

my view model class:

```
class MovieViewModel : ViewModel() {

var movieListResponse: List<Data> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
var detailsResponse: Details by mutableStateOf(Details())
private var error: String by mutableStateOf("")
var id : Int by mutableIntStateOf(0)

fun getMovieList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val api = RetrofitInstance.api.getMovies()
            movieListResponse = api.body()!!.data
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            error = e.message.toString()
        }

    }
}
fun getDetailsById() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val api = RetrofitInstance.api.getDetails(id = id)
            detailsResponse = api.body()!!
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            error = e.message.toString()
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Api interface:

```
interface ApiInterface {

@GET("movies?page=22")
suspend fun getMovies(

): Response<MoviesList>

@GET("movies/{movie_id} ")
suspend fun getDetails(
    @Path("movie_id") id: Int
): Response<Details>
}
```

UI compose:

```
   fun HomeScreenUi(moviesList: List<Data>, navController: NavHostController) {

LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            Modifier
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Transparent),
            content = {
                items(moviesList.size) {
                    HomeScreenUi(
                        itemIndex = it,
                        movies = moviesList,
                        navController = navController
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your api interface you can have something like

```
 @GET("movies")
suspend fun getMovies(@Query("page") pageNum:Number): Response<MoviesList>
```

where you pass in the pageNum as the page you want by keeping a state,

```
val api = RetrofitInstance.api.getMovies(pageNum = YOUR_PAGE_NUM)
```

You can store it in viewmodel state, or extract it from the latest movie data response, since you mentioned it also contains the last page num

Let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 1):

- If you're looking for a straightforward and hassle-free approach to
  implementing pagination without relying on the Paging 3 library, you
  may find useful insights in this repository:

[ComposePagingYT](https://github.com/philipplackner/ComposePagingYT)

- Alternatively, if you prefer utilizing Paging 3, you may want to
  Consider checking out:

[ComposePaging3Caching](https://github.com/philipplackner/ComposePaging3Caching)

- These repositories offer solutions that might align with your
  pagination needs.